# Add custom field in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am new to woocommerce. I want to create a select box which would give two option : custom size and standard size as follow image

[image]

[image]

As I click on custom size, I want to show some boxes as follow image

[image]

Is there any woocommerce plugin available or how can I customise it ??

Answer (score -1):

I think, You want to add custom field in into product tab.

I suggest to try it out readymade plugin for it once. It will provide you more flexibility on that.

Try plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-custom-product-data-fields/

Hope, this helps

Thanks